# Using a variable inside document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, php

I'd like to use a php variable instead of `#particles` in the below given code.

I tried using:

```
$(" . json_encode($paramnameid) . ").particleground({
```

but that didn't work.

```
$script = "<script type='text/javascript'>  
     document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {         
        particleground(document.getElementById('#particles'), {
                dotColor: " . json_encode($dotcolor) . ",
                lineColor: " . json_encode($linecolor) . "      
            });       
        }, false);       
    </script>";
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What actually is `$paramnameid` ? I mean, why the `json_encode()` ?

Comment: @kiarashi store the php variable in a hidden input then access it from javascript like `document.getElementById(document.getElementById('hiddeninput').value);`

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown: it's probably a string if it's a color, and strings in JS need to be quoted, which is what json_encode does... you can roll your own quotes, but that's risky if a quote or apos sneaks into the var. json_encode will make sure there's no extra toothpicks or broken nested quotes.